# jQuery show only table rows based on a specific columns rel attribute

Tags: jquery

I have this table that is currently 1200+ rows, of which these rows have a column that has a 3 dot (0.0.0) version number in them. So what I have at the moment at least unless a better way is presented is. The columns I am looking for have a class, and a rel. The rel has the same value as that displayed for that column.

What I also have is a select box, that has these same versions listed in it. The idea is to be able to select a version and have the table hide all rows with versions that are not the one selected, leaving only the selected version visible.

This is my failure of an attempt currently. I have tried a few variations but I keep ending up with a syntax error of some sort.

```
$('#client_version').change(function()
{
    var vers = $(this +' option:selected').val();
    $('.zm_ver').each(function(index, elem)
    {
        var theCol = $(elem);
        if(theCol.attr('rel') == vers){alert('yes');return true;}
        else
        {
            theCol.parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$('#client_version').change(function() {
    $('.zm_ver[rel!="'+this.value+'"]').parent().hide();
});
```

*Note:* `this.value` gives you the currently selected value in the `<select>`

Comment: doh, thought since I was wrapping it in the .each function that would overrule the select.